# Android navigation graph add extra fragment to stack on navigation

Tags: android, kotlin, android-navigation-graph

**Solution:**
both the accepted answer and the comment from @ianhanniballake work.
Due to the simplicity of the comment i'm going to use the comment one!
**Solution:**

I am trying the following:

There a three fragments in the navigation graph
1: dashboard (start)
2: list with items
3: item details

The user can navigate from `1` to `2` or directly from `1` to `3` for a couple of items. if the user goes from `1` to `3` I would like to go back to `2` first.

So, for example:

`>` means going forward in the stack

`<` means going backward in the stack

**case1:** when going to list first
`1 > 2 > 3 < 2 < 1`

**case2:** when going directly to the details
`1 > 3 < 2 < 1`

Is something like this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't just calling `navigate()` twice? First to 2, then to 3?

Comment: Already tried that but that doesn't work it will give me an error:
navigation destination ... (action for 3) is unknown to this NavController
but they do exists because i can call them separately

Comment: Well, after you `navigate` to 2, you have to use the actions that are on 2. Does your navigate call from 2 to 3 use an action on 2?

Comment: You where right i was using the wrong action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by overriding the back implementation which can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-custom-back), and returning to the fragment you wish when back is pressed.

I would create a new navigation action starting from `Fragment3` going to `Fragment2`. Make sure to select `popToInclusive` on this action. Then inside `Fragment3` do the following to ensure that when back is pressed, `Fragment2` will always be shown when navigating back in `Fragment3`:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    val callback: OnBackPressedCallback =
            object : OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
                override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
                    // Handle the back button event
                    findNavController().navigate(Fragment3FragmentDirections.actionFragment3ToFragment2())
                }
            }
    requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(this, callback)
}
```